# Angular 4: How to manipulate the "subscriber" element

Tags: angular

I'm refactoring my code and I'm using the next code:

**perfiles.component.ts**

```
this._ps.getPerfiles();
```

**perfiles.services.ts**

```
getPerfiles(){
    let path = "perfil"
    let dat = this._request.get(path);
    console.log(dat); // <-- Here appears the bottom message
    return dat;
  }
```

**request.service.ts**

```
get( path:string ){
    let token = this._ls.getToken();
    return this.http.get(`${this.sett.url}/${path}?token=${token}`)
                    .map(res => {
                      return res.json();
                    })
                    .subscribe(
                      data =>{
                        return data.data;
                      },
                      error =>{
                        this.handleError(error); // this function doesn't have any problem
                      }
                    );
  }
```

My issue is the next: I have receive a "subscriber" element, but i don't know how to use it. How do I get the data?

Please click over the next image to see big the issue.

[image]

Comment: dont subscribe inside of your service

Answer (score 0):

You must use the subscribe in component:

**perfiles.component.ts**

```
this._ps.getPerfiles().subscribe(anything => { 
  console.log(anything);
});
```

**perfiles.services.ts**

```
getPerfiles(){
    let path = "perfil"
    return this._request.get(path);
}
```

**request.service.ts**

```
get( path:string ){
    let token = this._ls.getToken();
    return this.http.get(`${this.sett.url}/${path}?token=${token}`)
                    .map(res => {
                      return res.json();
                    });
  }
```

This way you will respect the layers of Angular.

Comment: But I need to refactoring my code. if I using subscribers in Component I'll have a big code because I make many request. Any idea?

Comment: I think it's worth it's change, it would be cool you try to follow the styleguide.
[https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#data-services](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#data-services)